# IE7 peekaboo bug not responding to normal fixes

Tags: internet-explorer-7

When viewing the following page in IE7, then hovering over the google map at the top, all of the little "globe" images in the lists disappear, as well as the lines containing "Total number: x" and the show/hide list button. The disappearing elements both have styles of position:relative set in the links stylesheets.

http://wetlandinfo.derm.qld.gov.au/wetlands/MappingFandD/WetlandMapsAndData/SummaryInfo/B-422.jsp

Adding the min-width:0 style to the elements does not prevent the bug, and I haven't seen any other workarounds for the IE7 peekaboo bug.

Can anyone figure out how I can prevent the elements from disappearing?

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 0):

this probably won't help, but as soon as i moused over the maps i got this error:
`Line: 719
Character: 66
Code: 0
Error Message: 'this.yf' is null or not an object;`

and there was another error on page load.

i would at least start with those.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion changokun. These errors are from the google maps scripts and don't always occur. I don't think they're related to the problem. I am now completely redesigning the site so it is no longer an issue for me anyway.